# React Native: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm

**AAPT: error: resource android: attr/IStar not found.**

This error occurred suddenly, it was working fine last week.

[image]

I've tried many solutions but none works. Solutions tried:

1. Delete, reinstall npm, using `npm install`
2. clean gradle with `./gradlew clean` in /android
3. Cleaning npm cache with `npm cache clean --force`
4. add `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608m` in /android/gradle.properties
5. In /android/build.gradle, inside `ext{}` add `androidXCore = "1.6.0"`
6. `npm update @react-native-community/netinfo`
7. androidx.core:core-ktx:+ to androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0 but I've searched through my project, there is no 'androidx.core:core-ktx:+. So this solution I found is irrelevant.

**Version:**

```
"react-native": "0.63.4",

compileSdkVersion = 29
targetSdkVersion = 29
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this in your `android/buld.gradle` file.

```
def REACT_NATIVE_VERSION = new File(['node', '--print',"JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync(require.resolve('react-native/package.json'), 'utf-8')).version"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim())

allprojects {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            // Remove this override in 0.65+, as a proper fix is included in react-native itself.
            force "com.facebook.react:react-native:" + REACT_NATIVE_VERSION
        }
    }
```

Ref : https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210

Comment: It works! Gosh.. took me lots of hours to finally found a solution that works!. Thank you very much mate!

Answer (score 2):

There had been a series of build failures React Native & Expo users have been experiencing when building Android apps starting from November 4th 2022. Your issue is the same.

Since you are using `React-native 0.63` React-native has a new patch released for it. try updating your react-native in your `package.json` from `"react-native": "^0.63.4"` to `"react-native": "^0.63.5"` and try running `npm install` and everything will work fine.

The suggested answer by Thanhal will give you some headaches if you try to upgrade to a new version of react-native and forget to remove it from build.gradle.

for more info please refer to [This issue on github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210)

Comment: Ahh, thanks for your information and github link, will take note on that and will change later.

Comment: @AhChing11 have you got the time to try my suggestion?

Comment: So sorry I was rushing on deadlines, I'll try it next week.

Comment: I've tried upgrading to 0.63.5. But it returns 2 errors 1. `> A problem occurred evaluating script.
> Cannot run Project.afterEvaluate(Closure) when the project is already evaluated.` 2. `A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle`

Comment: Have you undo the changes on `android/build.gradle` before upgrading